# Как избавиться от подзапросов? Выборка sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, оптимизация

Задание: Добавить новый заголовок документа (одной командой insert);
-Номер документа = последний номер документа+1;
-Дата=текущая дата;
-Тип=расход,если документов типа "приход "больше ,чем документов типа "расход".В противном случае тип=приход.
-Учесть,что в таблице DMZ изначально может не быть ни одной строки.

Таблица DMZ - документ.DDM - дата, NDM- номер документа,PR - приход/расход (1-приход, 2-расход)товара.
Сам запрос есть :

```
INSERT INTO DMZ (DDM, NDM, PR)
SELECT
  GETDATE() DDM,
  (isnull((SELECT MAX(NDM) FROM DMZ), 0) + 1) NDM,
  CASE WHEN
      isnull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DMZ WHERE PR = 1), 0) > 
      isnull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DMZ WHERE PR = 2), 0)
    THEN 2
    ELSE 1
  END
```

[image: Диаграмма бд]

Запрос работает , но нужно его оптимизировать,заменив два запроса в операторе CASE на один.Как это сделать?

Вставляю диаграмму бд , если чем-то поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> нужно его оптимизировать,заменив два запроса в операторе CASE на
>   один. Как это сделать?

Можно получить `COUNT` для `PR=1` и `PR=2` одновременно с помощью `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH DMZ1 AS (SELECT PR FROM DMZ)
SELECT [1], [2]
FROM DMZ1
    PIVOT (COUNT(PR) FOR PR IN ([1], [2])) P;
```

Соответственно, исходный запрос может быть преобразован, например, в:

```
;WITH DMZ1 AS (SELECT PR FROM DMZ)
INSERT INTO DMZ (DDM, NDM, PR)
SELECT
    GETDATE() DDM,
    (isnull((SELECT MAX(NDM) FROM DMZ), 0) + 1) NDM,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM DMZ1
            PIVOT (COUNT(PR) FOR PR IN ([1], [2])) P
        WHERE [1] > [2]
        )
        THEN 2
        ELSE 1
    END;
```

Обычную группировку c `CASE` тоже можно использовать:

```
SELECT
    [1] = COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=1 THEN 1 END),
    [2] = COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=2 THEN 1 END)
FROM DMZ;
```

Использование `PIVOT` иногда даёт более лаконичную запись, но `CASE` более гибок (`PIVOT` хотя и представляет собой синтаксический сахар, однако в SqlServer синтаксис `PIVOT` развит не настолько хорошо как, например, в Oracle).

Обычная группировка с `CASE` здесь будет даже предпочтительнее, поскольку позволит и максимальный номер документа достать в одном запросе:

```
SELECT
    MAXNDM = ISNULL(MAX(NDM), 0),
    [1] = COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=1 THEN 1 END),
    [2] = COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=2 THEN 1 END)
FROM DMZ;
```

Соответственно, исходный запрос может быть преобразован в такой:

```
INSERT INTO DMZ (DDM, NDM, PR)
SELECT
    GETDATE(),
    ISNULL(MAX(NDM), 0) + 1,
    CASE WHEN
        COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=1 THEN 1 END) > 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN PR=2 THEN 1 END)
    THEN 2
    ELSE 1
  END
FROM DMZ;
```

Comment: А нельзя никак сделать это , применив подход как в этом запросе: 
SELECT
t.NTOV, 
SUM(s.KOL*(1-(d.PR-1)))-SUM(s.KOL*(d.PR-1)) as KOL,
SUM(s.CENA*(1-(d.PR-1)))-SUM(s.CENA*(d.PR-1)) as SUMMA
FROM DMS s
INNER JOIN TOV t on t.KTOV=s.KTOV
INNER JOIN DMZ d on d.NDM=s.NDM
GROUP BY t.NTOV
ORDER BY t.NTOV

?

Здесь определяется количество и сумма остатка (если 1 - приход, 2 - расход)

Comment: По сути,будет одно и то же , только вместо PIVOT Использовать просто CASE

Comment: @SoftySh, _"применив подход как в этом запросе"_ имеется ввиду обычная группировка? Да, можно. В данном случае это даже предпочтительнее (дополнил ответ).

Comment: Да,я это имела ввиду) Спасибо большое, теперь разобралась с двумя вариантами!